# Apply css on Datatable element on focusout event

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

We have a datatable column being rendered as below:

```
"render": function (data, type, row, meta){

var dropdownVarCodes = {
   source: varCodes
};

$(".varcode").autocomplete(dropdownVarCodes);
if(data == undefined) {
    data = '';
}
prop = '';
if(row.timesheetStatus == "COMPLETE"){
    prop = 'disabled="disabled"';
}
return '<input type="text" name="vCode" class="varcode" value="'+data+'" '+prop+' />';
```

Now we are trying to color the border red on focusout. We did a focusout event binding for the element as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
....
.........

$(document).on('focusout', '.varcode', function(e) {
   alert($('input.varcode').attr('name'));  // we get this correctly as 'vCode'
   var elem = e.target;   // elem = input.varcode, e = r.Event {type: "focusout", ........
   $(elem).css("border","2px solid red");   //elem = input.varcode
});

.....
........

});
```

we get the correct element too as can be seen by debugging (commented statements). Still we don't get the colored border for input element on focus out. Any ideas or pointers?

Note: Same code works if we have a input element created elsewhere on the document.

Comment: **UPDATE** :  We removed the $(elem).css() method and used $(elem).addClass('css class with red border'). It works now but once we click out of the input box, we loose the red border style. It can be cause we are using bootstrap-min.css which would be overriding again.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are overcomplicating the task? Here is a working example using chaining :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  drawCallback: function() {
    $('#example input.varCode').autocomplete({
      source: tags
    }).focusout(function() {
      $(this).css('border', '2px solid red')
    }) 
  }  
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nudwjo7c/**

I consider the code you are using in `render()` as "bad practice" (no offense). Separate data and scripting, espcially when you are working with additional plugins that need to work inside the dataTable. Better to initialise those in a `drawCallback` or `initComplete`.

---

**To clarify**: The only thing you should do in `render()` is

```
render: function (data, type, row, meta){
  var prop = row.timesheetStatus == "COMPLETE" ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '';
  return '<input type="text" name="vCode" class="varcode" value="' + data + '" ' + prop + ' />';
}
```

You actually initialise `autocomplete()` 1+2+3+4+5 etc times, one time per `render()` per `<input>`, so the first input is at the end initialised `n` times, the number of rows. A huge overhead.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. Am bit new to UI development, will keep this noted. Using .css() wasn't working, i created a css class and used addClass(), it works now. Though it looses focus again once we click outside the input boxes. Could be cause of bootstrap-min.css.

Comment: @pranav I too prefer using classes, try using `!important`, see updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nudwjo7c/1/**

Answer (score 0):

I reckon this works:

```
    $(document).on('focusout', '.varcode', function(event) {
         $(event.target).css("border","2px solid red");  
     });
```

Comment: Tried this too, didn't work. Though it seems same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your CSS is overridden. Please check your styles.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('focusout', '.varcode', function(e) {
    alert($('input.varcode').attr('name'));  // we get this correctly as 'vCode'
    var elem = e.target;   // elem = input.varcode, e = r.Event {type: "focusout",
      $(elem).css("border","2px solid red");   //elem = input.varcode
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="vCode" class="varcode" value="MEOWWWWwwww!!!" />
```

Comment: Am not very sure if the css getting overridden. So, I tried like this  `$(elem).css("border","2px solid red!important");` so this will take precedence. Still same result.

Comment: Could be browser-specific. Have you tested elsewhere?

Comment: Its working if we create a class and use addClass() method. Though i loose red border once we focus out of the text box. Bootstap-min.css can be the cause.